# why are the cells in my tableview resizing

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have a tableview with 2 cells. for some reason the cells get resized when I open in simulator. Trying to understand why. I added image of view.

this is the view code. for now i just wish the cells to get created at the height I set in IB

```
import UIKit

class userMenuViewController:    BaseViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

var surveyNameArr = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (surveyNameArr.count)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell2TableViewCell



    return (cell)

}



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    addSlideMenuButton()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

[image: image of cells in table]
[image: this is the image of my view]

Comment: Provide more details. Like anybody can tell by looking at your screenshot. Show me what did you do in storyboard and code so I can tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i was looking for:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
}
```